# Update Function View in Django is not saving the editings

Tags: python, django

When im writing or editing something in front_end of my,its not saving those editing. it redirect to detail view and shows earlier data.where am i doing wrong?

my code

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
# Create your moels here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,default='')
    body = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Forms.py

```
from .models import Post
from django import forms

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','body']
```

app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ path('post/<int:pk>/edit/',views.edit_view, name = "edit_view")]
```

Views.py

```
def edit_view(request,pk):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except:
        raise Http404('Page Not Found')
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None,instance= post)
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return redirect('detail_view', pk=pk)
    else:
        return render(request, 'edit.html',{'form_edit': form})
```

Template
edit.html

```
<form method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form_edit.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you are calling `save()` method only if instance's slug value is not set. You need to rewrite model's `save()` like this:

```
def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Now `super().save()` will be called in both cases if `self.slug` is filled and if it's empty.

Comment: it works now! thanks for your correction.Can you please explain a little bit why wrong indentation in super() statement caused such error? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak `super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)` is actually perform instance saving. Indented line will be called only `if not self.slug`. But for existing instances this condition is not truly. On the other side not indented `super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)` will be called each time you save instance and so your instances will be updated properly.